# Insert or Update in Sybase SQLAnywhere

Tags: php, database, odbc, sybase, sqlanywhere

How can I insert a row in database `(Sybase SQL Anywhere 12.5)` if it does not exist, and update if it exists?

I'm trying following:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO customer_info (user_id, fname, lname) VALUES(:user_id, :fname, :lname)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fname= :fname2, lname= :lname2');

$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);  
$stmt->bindParam(':fname', $_POST['fname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':lname', $_POST['lname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);      
$stmt->bindParam(':fname2', $_POST['fname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':lname2', $_POST['lname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

It gives following ***error***:

> [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Syntax error near 'ON' on line 1

Is it some compatibility issue? 
How can I do it it?

Answer (score 3):

Add `ON EXISTING UPDATE` to the insert statement, for example:

```
INSERT INTO customer_info (user_id,fname,lname) ON EXISTING UPDATE VALUES(Value1,Value2,Value3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read into `REPLACE INTO`

an example syntax for this would be:

```
REPLACE INTO my_table (pk_id, col1) VALUES (5, '123');
```

This automatically identifies the primary key and finds a matching row to update, inserting a new one if none is found.